# Unable to deploy, failing on slug prepare/upload

Tags: error, magento2.3.1, deployment, magento2-cloud

There is an issue in some of our shared environments where deployment fails intermittently on the "Preparing slugs" step. No other details are in the error log. Has anyone experienced this or can think of possible root causes?

```
Deploying applications
  Starting deployment
  Preparing slugs
  E: Failed to upload slugs
  E: Command '['ssh', u'2.xxxxxx.ent.magento.cloud', 'sudo /etc/platform/xxxxxx/rebuild_slug.sh /mnt/shared/slugs/xxxxxxxxxxx-mymagento-xxxxxxxxxx']' returned non-zero exit status 255

E: Error: Cannot complete deployment
```

We have confirmed that we still have usable space left on disk, although maybe it's not enough of a margin. Currently allocated at 15GB. Our diskspace for the shared environments (xx and xx_2):

```
xxxxxxxx_2@i-02719996b6e941c57:~$ df -h
Filesystem                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                               10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                              13G  480K   13G   1% /run
/dev/xvda1                                         59G   14G   43G  24% /
tmpfs                                              32G   24K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                             5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                              32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdi                                          20G   11G  9.2G  54% /data/exports
/dev/xvdj                                          50G   40G  9.1G  82% /data/mysql
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/shared                                20G   11G  9.0G  55% /mnt/shared
/dev/loop0                                        228M  228M     0 100% /app/xxxxxxxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/shared/xxxxxxxx/var              20G   11G  9.0G  55% /app/xxxxxxxx/var
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/shared/xxxxxxxx/app/etc          20G   11G  9.0G  55% /app/xxxxxxxx/app/etc
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/shared/xxxxxxxx/pub/media        20G   11G  9.0G  55% /app/xxxxxxxx/pub/media
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/shared/xxxxxxxx/pub/static       20G   11G  9.0G  55% /app/xxxxxxxx/pub/static
/dev/loop1                                        230M  230M     0 100% /app/xxxxxxxx_2
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/shared/xxxxxxxx_2/var          20G   11G  9.0G  55% /app/xxxxxxxx_2/var
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/shared/xxxxxxxx_2/app/etc      20G   11G  9.0G  55% /app/xxxxxxxx_2/app/etc
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/shared/xxxxxxxx_2/pub/media    20G   11G  9.0G  55% /app/xxxxxxxx_2/pub/media
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/shared/xxxxxxxx_2/pub/static   20G   11G  9.0G  55% /app/xxxxxxxx_2/pub/static
```

**FOLLOWUP:**
Magento Support identified our slug file as being corrupt. They removed it and then deployment has worked ever since.

Comment: Is this dick space allocated?

Comment: Good question. Updated my question with disk space information.

Comment: @Andrew Any solution to this issue? We are also facing the same.

Comment: @BhargavMehta Please see my followup comment and the bottom of my original post. Best of luck!

Comment: Yes we also raised the ticket to restart the server and get it fixed